# Pascal running multi procedures at the same time

Tags: pascal

Can Pascal run multi procedures at the same time?

If yes, can anyone provide the code?

Since I would like to display a clock on screen (command prompt) but at the same time I want the program also accepts inputs.

I use

```
write(DateTimeToStr(now))
```

to display the current time and use a repeat loop to keep flashing it, but the repeat loop makes accepting inputs at the same time not possible as the cursor keeps flashing

Comment: What Pascal implementation are you using, Delphi. FPC or what?  You can certainly run multiple threads in application written in Dellphi or FPC.

Comment: I use Dev-Pascal, developed by Bloodshed Software

Comment: Since my school don't want to install too large file size on the computer

Comment: I pity you. That only supports a really really ancient version of freepascal, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pascal, as a language, has no multiprocessing/multithreading capabilities. So, no.

Now, I guess you're using that antique language for a reason, and probably in a more recent implementation like FreePascal, and that, for example, has a threading implementation. Giving you a full tour of multithreading in general and in FreePascal in detail would definitely be too much for a single answer, so go and search google for "freepascal multithreading".

Comment: Is there any ways to keep updating the current time and accept inputs at the same time?

Comment: um, you don't seem to have understood my answer.

Comment: Oic. I understand your meaning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start the Free Pascal textmode IDE and you'll see that the timer runs without actually using threading.

Event driven principles and updating the clock when idle goes a long way...